# How to pass noisy images as input and original images as labels in Keras - Autoencoders

Tags: keras, tensorflow, dataset, autoencoder, python-3.x

I want to make denoising autoencoder, I've added some noise to images, and i want to use them for training, original images will be used as label.

Reading the keras documentation I've found that I need to make generator, since my dataset is large. The function **flow_from_directory method** from [keras documentation](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/#image-data-preprocessing) is good fit. But I have found one problem.

**class_mode: 'input'** option from **flow_from_directory(directory):** *method is saying:  images identical to input images (mainly used to work with autoencoders)*

**My question is: 'How can I pass as input noisy images and then pass as labels original clean images'**?